# Reshape by only two columns in pandas

Tags: python, pivot-table, reshape

This should be a simple question, but I think I'm just missing the keyword for what I should be searching for.

Suppose I have a two-column long dataset, like follows:

```
test = pd.DataFrame(
       {
          'color': ['white', 'white', 'white', 
                    'red', 'red', 'red', 
                    'black', 'black', 'black'],
           'value': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
       })
```

How can I get it into the following format:

```
    white   red    black
    1        4       7
    2        5       8 
    3        6       9
```

I realize this should be a simple pivot function like:

`test.pivot('color', 'value')`, but this produces the values in the diagonal with surrounding NaN. Is there any way around this?

Comment: problem is there is no logical connection between the values in each row, and mixing the order of one of the column will make as much sense, so if you know the number of each color showing is 3, make a column of repeating 1,2,3 and set it as pivot index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
test["id"]=test.groupby("color")["color"].cumcount()

test.pivot(index="id", columns="color", values="value")
```

Outputs:

```py
color  black  red  white
id
0          7    4      1
1          8    5      2
2          9    6      3
```

Comment: What a wizard! If you don't mind - why does this work rather than when I manually generate a new id, such as an appropriately long np.arange()? Or, if you recall, where you learned this trick? I searched high and low and couldn't seem to find many questions in my situation (or perhaps I was using the wrong keyword...)

Comment: Haha, glad it worked:) so - you need to take ```cumcount()``` with ```groupby(...)``` (so it will count separately for each group) to get the proper id- otherwise like you said - you will get a diagonal. It just assigns row number to each occurrence within the group in order in which they occur.

Answer (score 0):

I have done some quick solution using the group by function using the pandas library

```
 for i in test.groupby('color'):
     print(i[0])
     for j in range(len(i[1])):
         for k in i[1].values:
             print(k[1])
         break
```

Output:

```
black
7
8 
9
red
4  
5
6
white
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create series, reset indexes, and recreate a dataframe from the 3 series :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'color': ['white', 'white', 'white', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'black', 'black', 'black'],
'value': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]})

serie_white = df['value'][df['color'] == "white"].reset_index(drop=True)
serie_red = df['value'][df['color'] == "red"].reset_index(drop=True)
serie_black = df['value'][df['color'] == "black"].reset_index(drop=True)

result = pd.DataFrame({'white': serie_white, 'red': serie_red, 'black': serie_black})
print(result)
```

Output :

```
   white  red  black
0      1    4      7
1      2    5      8
2      3    6      9
```